# Partitioning micro sdcard fails with sdcard reader

Tags: windows, partitioning, diskpart

I'm using a diskpart script from C# to completely clean a micro sdcard and create a single partition taking the entire available space. This is the script I'm using:

```
select disk <n>
clean
automount disable
create partition primary
select partition 1
format fs=fat32 quick
active
```

This seems to work perfectly fine when I plug my micro sdcard into a USB adapter, but I get an error when trying the same approach with the same micro sdcard plugged in using the internal sdcard reader. In that case the command "format fs=fat32 quick" returns the error:

```
There is no volume selected.
Please select a volume and try again.
```

What I see is that in the first case, after creating a partition, a volume is also properly created and selected. When using an sdcard reader no volume is created at all. Tried some other approaches but all are failing. I tried to use another partitioning tool and it was able to format properly. Why is there a difference here and how do I write a script that works in both cases? Thanks!

Comment: No need to 'select partition 1' and no need to make it active. Use 'Assign' at the end to assign a drive letter then try it again.

Comment: The SD card reader may have a limit to size of the cards it can read. I have one which can't read over 16gb.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas assign after create partition primary returns the same exact error. Both a regular partitioning tool and windows itself from the file manager can format the partition created. Only diskpart is unable to format.

Comment: Are you plugging in the card reader into a USB3 port? Try a usb2 only port if you have one

Comment: The card reader is integrated. It is probably a USB device anyway, but no idea what kind.

Comment: So the card reader works with every other windows tool you have apart from diskpart?

Comment: Also try 'select volume 1' in diskpart

Comment: Yes, it seems to work with everything else. volume 1 is boot volume... should I select that?

Comment: You must 'select disk x' with x being the card reader disk, then select volume x which will be the volume of the card in the card reader

Comment: There is no volume related to the sdcard: "when using an sdcard reader no volume is created at all". I only have volumes related to partitions in the internal hard disk. The new volume is created instead when using a USB adapter.

Comment: Absolutely no idea, apart from to try another SD card. Sorry